# Can I use CRTP to enforce an interface?

Tags: c++, c++20, crtp

I want to enforce at compile time that a class implements an interface using CRTP.
I want to avoid virtual functions (I don't want a vtable).
Is this possible?

Below is my attempt to enforce that a function it implemented, but it only errors if `Required()` is used in the program... which would happen regardless of whether I inherit from IFoo.

```cpp
template <typename Foo>
class IFoo {
  public:
    // Rule I want to enforce: derived class must define this function
    int Required() = delete;

    // I've also seen this suggestion, but all it achieves is infinite recursion
    // if Required() isn't implemented in the derived class
    //int Required() { return static_cast<Foo*>(this)->Required(); }
};

class MyFoo : public IFoo<MyFoo> {
  public:
    // Required() is not declared or defined
};

int main() {
    MyFoo f;
    // f.Required(); // I will only get a compile error if I use Required()
    return 0;
}
```

See in godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/fGGTGv3ME

Comment: I realized I missed the best part of your question and removed the answer I made. What happens in your program if a class with an unimplemented `Required` is defined? What happens if that class is used, but `Required` is not used?

Comment: There's no issue if a class with an unimplemented `Required` is defined - as long as `Required` isn't used.

Comment: Ok, so, you only require a compilation error if `Required` is used, but isn't implemented in the derived class?

Comment: Yes. You can click the godbolt link and try it for yourself.

Comment: Ok, so, how does the `static_assert` suggestion I made below work in that situation?

Comment: The question does not make sense. It is always a compilation error if a function is used but  not implemented in a class. No special efforts are necessary to achieve this.

Comment: usually its' the recursive template what enforces interface not other way around, but always, at compile time by standard. Some compilers behave differently and you may fall into that trap. If a function have been used in any way and doesn't exist, in most cases which do not involve SFINAE, concept constraints or `if constexpr` the code is ill-formed regardless its ability to compile.

Answer (score 0):

An infinite recursion prevention may be a `static_assert` making sure the call isn't a call to itself:

```cpp
template <typename Foo>
class IFoo {
public:  
    int Required() {
        static_assert( &IFoo<Foo>::Required != &Foo::Required );
        return static_cast<Foo*>(this)->Required(); 
    }
};
```

Comment: With that static assert, your function is now as useful as `int Required() = delete;`
Meaning: it gives a compiler error ONLY IF `MyFoo::Required()` is called in the program.
However, this is giving me an idea about how I could enforce the interface...

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution that I can think of. Specifying each requirement is very cumbersome with metafunction calls, so this is a poor design pattern.
I definitely wouldn't use it compared to C++20 concepts.

```
template <typename Foo>
class IFoo {
  public:
    void _requirements() __attribute__((used)) {
        // Check the Foo has a function called Required
        static_assert( &Foo::Required );

        // Further metafunction calls to check required input & output types
        // ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put `static_assert` inside the base constructor:

```
template <typename T>
concept HasRequired = requires (T& t) { t.Required(); };

template <typename Foo>
struct IFoo {
  constexpr IFoo() {
    static_assert(HasRequired<Foo>);
  }
};
```

So that when trying to construct a derived class that does not provide the specified function, the assertion fires causing compilation to fail:

```
class MyFoo : public IFoo<MyFoo> {
  public:
    // Required() is not declared or defined
};

MyFoo f; // error
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/of8xjo5hc)